# Unable to insert mutiple values to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I need help on this: I am trying to insert multiple values to database using a webpage as the interface. When I try to save I get the error

> "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'values'."

Below C# code for your reference.

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=INHRPSM1D7C;Initial Catalog=Controller_Forecast;Integrated Security=True;");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public void refress()
    {
        TextBox1.Text = "";
        TextBox2.Text = "";
        TextBox3.Text = "";
        TextBox4.Text = "";
        TextBox5.Text = "";
        TextBox6.Text = "";
        TextBox7.Text = "";
        TextBox8.Text = "";
        TextBox9.Text = "";
        TextBox10.Text = "";
        TextBox11.Text = "";
        TextBox12.Text = "";
        DropDownList1.Text = "";
        DropDownList2.Text = "";
    }

    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Controller_Forecast(C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8,C9,C10,C11,C12,C13) values('" +
            TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + 
            "','" + TextBox4.Text + "','" + TextBox5.Text + "','" + TextBox6.Text +
            "','" + TextBox7.Text + "','" + TextBox8.Text + "','" + TextBox9.Text +
            "','" + TextBox10.Text + "','" + TextBox11.Text + "','" + TextBox12.Text +
            "','" + DropDownList1.Text + "','" + DropDownList2.Text + "','" +
            DropDownList3.Text + "'),values('" + TextBox13.Text + "','" +
            TextBox14.Text + "','" + TextBox15.Text + "','" +
            TextBox16.Text + "','" + TextBox17.Text + "','" +
            TextBox18.Text + "','" + TextBox19.Text + "','" +
            TextBox20.Text + "','" + TextBox21.Text + "','" +
            TextBox22.Text + "','" + TextBox23.Text + "','" +
            TextBox24.Text + "','" + DropDownList4.Text + "','" +
            DropDownList5.Text + "','" + DropDownList6.Text + "')",con);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Literal1.Text = "Data Updated Successfully!!!";
            con.Close();
            refress();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Literal1.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        refress();
        Literal1.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Something is wrong in this huge command string you're creating with concatenation, probably some missing/extra commas or single quotes. Use debugger and check how exactly this command looks like after concatenation. Or even better - don't use concatenation at all since it leads to sql injection vulnerability and use parameterized queries instead.

Comment: I don't have debugger installed in my system, can you modify the query and paste it

Comment: You're calling `values(...)` twice, which is invalid SQL syntax.

Comment: Oh boy, [little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) is going to have a field day with this one.

Comment: The query has VALUES() in it twice. Make sure the number of data items in your VALUES() clause matches the number of field names you specify at the beginning, also.

Comment: @MohammedSiddiqPS Surely you have debugger installed. It is Visual Studio itself.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev, I have using Web Expression builder to develop it

Comment: @MohammedSiddiqPS in this case I really suggest you to use Visual Studio Community Edition instead. It is free and has a lot of benefits over Web Expression builder.

Comment: @Andy Korneyev I did some changes as mentioned by richardsonmarkj, now I am getting this error "String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated. "

Comment: @MohammedSiddiqPS this means you're trying to insert into one of the columns in your query string exceeding column length set in DB.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev All the values that are being passed are less then the column size

Comment: Can you show the example data and the DB table schema?

Comment: Voted to close as typo, unlikely to benefit future readers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do 2 sets of values like your trying to do with an [INSERT statement](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776381%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Your effectively doing:

```
INSERT INTO Controller_Forecast(C1,C2...)
VALUES(...loads of values...)
VALUES(...Loads of more values...)
```

This isn't valid. To insert 2 sets of data, which is what it looks like you're trying to do you can do 2 INSERT INTO statements or split the list of values with commas like so:

*Multiple insert statements*

```
INSERT INTO Controller_Forecast(C1,C2...)
VALUES(...your first set of values...)
INSERT INTO Controller_Forecast(C1,C2...)
VALUES(...your second set of values...)
```

*Separating with commas*

```
INSERT INTO Controller_Forecast(C1,C2...)
VALUES(...your first set of values...), (...second set of values...)
```

However, this seems inefficient and you'd be better off writing this in a store procedure and parameterising your values to avoid sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

You have twice "values". Can you try this?

> "insert into
>   Controller_Forecast(C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8,C9,C10,C11,C12,C13)
>   values('" +
>               TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + 
>               "','" + TextBox4.Text + "','" + TextBox5.Text + "','" + TextBox6.Text +
>               "','" + TextBox7.Text + "','" + TextBox8.Text + "','" + TextBox9.Text +
>               "','" + TextBox10.Text + "','" + TextBox11.Text + "','" + TextBox12.Text +
>               "','" + DropDownList1.Text + "','" + DropDownList2.Text + "','" +
>               DropDownList3.Text + "')",con);